# Using Organization Browser webpart in publishing site even if MySite is not configured

Tags: 2013, my-site, organization-browser

Can I use Organiation Browser web part in a publishing site page even if MySite is not configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you must have successfully performed a User Profile Synchronization to have the organizational data within SharePoint to be displayed in the Organization Browser WebPart.

More to read: [Organization browser in SharePoint 2010](http://sampathlive.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/organization-browser-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: The link you gave which compares Org Chart and Org Browser, looks like Org Chart is a 3rd party product and not that something that comes with SharePoint, right?

Comment: @FrankMartin that's right. And I'll remove the link since SP.SE don't allow commercial 3rd party products. I made an error, sorry. But you still need User Profil Sync before you see anything in SharePoint Organization Browser Web Part.